# Processing incoming APP link Titanium Studio Iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, callback, request, titanium-mobile

I'm using Titanium's facebook module to show a apprequests dialog. I could send application request and when I get into the facebook app and hit the notification, I could get into my app.

But, how do I process the incoming URL? I went through the link [Deep link with requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/#step4)

that shows how to do it with Objective C. Any help on how to implement it with Titanium Studio would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the arguments with this snippet :

```
var cmd = Ti.App.getArguments();
if ( (getTypeOf(cmd) == 'object') && cmd.hasOwnProperty('url') ) {
    Ti.App.launchURL = cmd.url;
    Ti.API.info( 'Launched with url = ' + Ti.App.launchURL );
}
```

this is called the URLScheme, if you are looking for online docs!

Source: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120393/custom-url-scheme---iphone--android